# Passing Object to DistributedCache set method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using this package `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis`.
What is the way to pass `tModel` to set and get from cache.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int test1 { get; set; }

    public string test2 { get; set; }
}

var tModel = new TestModel();
tModel.test1 = 1;
tModel.test2 = "abc";

_distributedCache.Set("model", tModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would serialize the data to JSON and persist it as a string:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// ...

// Set
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tModel);
_distributedCache.SetString("model", jsonData);

// Get
var jsonData = _distributedCache.GetString("model");
var tModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestModel>(jsonData);
```

Notice I used the `GetString` and `SetString` extension methods here, rather than the low-level `Get` and `Set` method which takes and returns bytes. There are also async methods available.